# CSS property background-blend-mode does not Validate in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, html, css, visual-studio, asp.net-core

The issue is as simple as this: Visual Studio code will not interpret the CSS property background-blend-mode. It says it is not a known CSS property name. I am looking to see if anyone knows a fix or workaround for this.

That's the code I am using below. Intellisense gives me the error for it, and it won't work when I try to run my asp.net razor page. Everything else is fine. It just will not acknowledge that its a css property.

`background-blend-mode: difference, normal;`